# There are no $3$ linearly independent lightlike vectors such that $u+v+w = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, semi-riemannian-geometry

Consider the Lorentz-Minkowski space $E^n_1$, also known as $\mathbb{L}^n$. I want to prove that there are not lightlike linearly independent vectors $u, v, w \in E^n_1$  such that $u + v + w = 0$. How to do it? I'm still unfamiliar with the intuition behind such space.

Comment: Does this space have 2 spacelike and one timelike variables? or what if not?

Comment: @coffeemath Those are all hypotheses I have.

Comment: I don't see how this can be true... can't we take one of the vectors from the future light cone, say $\vec{u}$, and the other two to be $-\frac{1}{2}\vec{u}$? Don't we need to say that they are non-coplanar?

Comment: @RandomMathGuy The title (but not the body) specifies that the three vectors must be linearly independent.

Comment: @Travis I should learn to read the titles more carefully!

Comment: @RandomMathGuy and I need to learn how to type more carefully, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Suppose there were. Expand $$0 = [{\bf u} + {\bf v} + {\bf w}] \cdot [{\bf u} - ({\bf v} + {\bf w})]$$ to conclude that ${\bf v} \cdot {\bf w} = 0$.

> **Additional hint** What is the matrix representation of the bilinear form $\cdot$ with respect to the basis $({\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w})$?

Comment: Since I wrote this answer, OP edited the question to address the case of $n$-dimensional Minkowski space $\mathbb L^n$ rather than just the special case $n = 3$. The initial hint still leads to a solution for the general case, but of course $({\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w})$ is not a basis of $\mathbb L^n$ for $n \neq 3$.

Comment: Shouldn't I conclude ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf w} = 0$ instead?

Comment: I don't see how---after all, the expression is symmetric in ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf w}$.

Comment: $0 = [u + v + w] \cdot [u - (v + w)] = u\cdot u - u\cdot v + u\cdot w + v\cdot u - v\cdot v + v\cdot w + w\cdot u - w\cdot v + w\cdot w = 2 u\cdot w$, since $u\cdot u = v\cdot v = w\cdot w = 0$ (lightlike vectors) and $v\cdot u - u\cdot v = 0, v\cdot w - w\cdot v = 0$. Would you correct me?

Comment: So by concluding ${\bf v} \cdot {\bf w} = 0$, I conclude that only $2$ of the $3$ original vectors are linearly independent, is that it?

Comment: Expanding gives $0 = {\bf u} \cdot {\bf u} - ({\bf v} + {\bf w}) \cdot ({\bf v} + {\bf w}) = -({\bf v} \cdot {\bf v} + 2 {\bf v} \cdot {\bf w} + {\bf w} \cdot {\bf w}) = -2 {\bf v} \cdot {\bf w}$.

Comment: Not directly anyway. By symmetry of notation, we also have ${\bf u} \cdot {\bf v} = {\bf w} \cdot {\bf u} = 0$, but for $n = 3$ that means all pairs of basis vectors are orthogonal, which implies that $\cdot$ is the zero bilinear form, a contradiction.